# After opening all args with :ba, go back to a single split

Tags: buffers, split, merge

Generally when opening more than two or three files in vim, I use a single split, navigating between the files/buffers with `:n`/`:N`. Sometimes, however, I want to open all of them in visible splits at once (`:ba`/`:vert ba`), such as to move the cursor in each to the next occurrence of a search pattern.

Afterward, I usually want to go back to the single split, but the obvious methods to reduce the split count are quitting (drops the buffers) or moving the splits around (e.g. `CTRL-w L`, awkward and requires double the screen real estate). Is there a better way?

Comment: `:only` Or `<C-w>o` might interest you.

Comment: That does seem useful. It does strange things to the buffer sequence, though; if I opened `vim a.py b.py c.py d.py` and then ran `:ba`, then `:only` while focused on the `c.py` buffer, Vim considers c to be the first file, and moving with `:n` goes c > b > c > d. (OTOH `:n`, `:N` goes c > b > a, so it's merely strange and annoying, not a *big* problem).

Comment: Depends on how you are getting to c.py: `:ball` might not change the current position in the arglist, so you’re still considered on the first argument. Try `:args` to debug that; the arglist (which `:next`/`:prev` manipulate) is not really the same as the buffer list, and “buffer sequence” isn’t really a term I’m familiar with for vim.